# How to rebuild directory buffer in ECB?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

This is basically the question. I've added a new directory, since opening ECB, but the directory buffer isn't updated. How do I force it to update? Tried <kbd>C-c . s</kbd> and `revert-buffer` in the directories buffer to no effect.

**EDIT**

Sorry, this is weird, I actually found `M-x ecb-update-directories-buffer` but it won't update it :S... Is this something known to happen? This is just a regular directory I've added except the name is one letter long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ECB, but <kbd>g</kbd> is the usual Emacs binding for a 'refresh buffer contents' function.

Comment: To whomever: If you down-voted this answer because it's completely incorrect, that's fine, *but leave a comment to say so, because otherwise I don't know*. I'll happily delete it if it's unhelpful, but at this point I'm still only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + click on the node you want to refresh.